# How to call for a monolog from the index.php?

Tags: php, monolog, php-di

There is example of using Monolog with PHP-DI (from manual, there are 2 files - index.php and config.php:

```
<?php
// config.php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

return [
    // ...

    Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class => DI\factory(function () {
        $logger = new Logger('mylog');

        $fileHandler = new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', Logger::DEBUG);
        $fileHandler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter());
        $logger->pushHandler($fileHandler);

        return $logger;
    }),
];
```

This config.php is using in the below code:

```
// index.php    
use DI\ContainerBuilder;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder;
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ . '/config.php');
$container = $containerBuilder->build();
```

How could I use it now in index.php? Regularly I use Monolog this  way:

```
$log = new Logger('name'); 
$log->warning('Foo');
```

But **how to call it with Container**? 
I was able to do it in simple $container->set(), $container->get() mode. But in this way  using Container Builder I can't find a way to do it. Moreover  when I make `var_dump($container)` there are no any logger's signs in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `$log = new Logger('name')` with:

```php
$log = $container->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
```

See this part of the documentation: http://php-di.org/doc/getting-started.html#3-create-the-objects